# Please can you check my proof of $f$ is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I tried to prove:

If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and if $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $[a,b]$.

Please can you tell me if my proof is correct:

Proof: Since $f'$ is continuous there exists $M \ge 0$ such that $|f'(x)| \le M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. That is, $\lim_{h \to 0} {|f(x+h) - f(x)| \over |h|} \le M$. In particular for $x,y \in [a,b]$ choose $h$ so that $y = x+h$. Then 
$$ {|f(y) - f(x)| \over |y-x|}  \le {|f(x+{h\over 2}) - f(x)| \over {|h|\over 2}} \le M$$
which shows that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary.

Thank you.

Comment: Why the division by two of $\;h\;$ there?

Comment: be carefull: the first inequality is true only for $h$ small enough, ou you can't take $y = x+h$ as you want an inequality for all $x,y$.

Comment: You have not address the issue of whether or not the same h will work for all x. And, depending on your definition of Lipschitz, you may have to show $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$ for one fixed $M$ and *all* $x,y\in[a,b]$. You might consider the mean value theorem or the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you directly use MVT ( Lagrange's theorem ) ?

$$\forall\,x,y\in[a,b]\;\exists\,c\in(x,y)\;\;s.t.\;\;\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|=\left|f'(c)\right|\le M\implies$$

$$\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|\;\;\;\forall\,x,y\in[a,b]$$